# Application momentarily hangs main thread

Tags: vb.net, windows, backgroundworker, freeze, ui-thread

I am trying to connect to a SFTP server using WinSCP and vb.net. Everything goes well and the file uploads/downloads correctly but after it has finished, if I interact with the form in any way (ie. Pressing a button) the main thread hangs for about 10-15 seconds. Then it resumes and never hangs again unless I restart the application. This seems strange to me because I am doing all WinSCP functions on a separate thread using a `BackgroundWorker`. I am using `mySession.putFiles` for uploading and `GetFiles` for downloading. This seems to only happen when downloading/uploading files.

Here is a snippet of my code which is based on [This Example](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#vbnet):

```
Using mySession As Session = New Session
' Connect
mySession.Open(mySessionOptions)

' Upload files
Dim myTransferOptions As New TransferOptions
myTransferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary

Dim transferResult As TransferOperationResult
transferResult = mySession.GetFiles("KidsBank/FVbal.txt", "FVbal.txt") 

transferResult.Check()
ConsolePrint("Got fv")
transferResult = mySession.GetFiles("KidsBank/FERbal.txt", "FERbal.txt")
transferResult.Check()
ConsolePrint("Got fer")
transferResult = mySession.GetFiles("KidsBank/AZbal.txt", "AZbal.txt")
transferResult.Check()
ConsolePrint("Got az")

LoadingText.Text = "Downloading Check Dates..."

transferResult = mySession.GetFiles("KidsBank/FVlastcheck.txt", "FVlastcheck.txt") 
transferResult.Check()
ConsolePrint("Got fv check")
transferResult = mySession.GetFiles("KidsBank/FERlastcheck.txt", "FERlastcheck.txt")
transferResult.Check()
ConsolePrint("Got fer check")
transferResult = mySession.GetFiles("KidsBank/AZlastcheck.txt", "AZlastcheck.txt")
transferResult.Check()
ConsolePrint("Got az check")
```

Comment: Could it be your `ConsolePrint` method which is causing the problem? Also, why is `LoadingText.Text = ...` in a backgroundworker?

Comment: Removing ConsolePrint did the trick. Very strange since it only writes to a richtextbox...

Comment: You cannot access GUI controls from a background thread.

Comment: You haven't, by chance, set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to False have you? **(Don't do this if you haven't)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the ConsolePrint command was the issue since I was using `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` in False for debugging.